# What is the domain of this differential equation/its solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the differential equation

$$
xy' = 2y
$$

with solution

$$
y=x^2
$$

I am specifically referring to a problem in an ODE textbook. The book says that the domain/interval of solution is $$\mathbf{R} - \{0\}$$

However, I beg to disagree because the differential equation is not expressed in quotient form like:

$$ y' = \frac{2y}{x} $$

And I would like to include zero in domain set. What is a consistent way of defining domains for cases like the above?

**EDIT**: I am posting the original question below:

> Prove that $$y=x^2$$ is a solution of the differential equation $$ xy' = 2y $$
>   Also, be sure to state the common interval for which the solution and the DE make sense.

(Paraphrased from Tenenbaum and Pollard, 1963)

Thanks!

Comment: In saying that $y=x^2$ you're supposing a specific initial condition. Was this given?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution of the differential equation includes the step $\ln |y|=2\ln |x| +C$ which does not include zero in the domain.  Any steps after that would have to provide for that exception as well.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!

Comment: I have one question though. The original textbook question only asks to verify/prove for which you do not have to solve the equation. You would do good to just verify that it satisfies the DE. How then would one decide to include or throw away the zero?

Comment: The text should have included the exception in the answer.  Another inaccuracy is that in fact the exception can be removed by simply observing (as you have done) that the solution works when x, y and y' are all zero.  So your original answer should be accepted by your teacher.